# How can I take keys with me while swimming?

Tags: safety, swimming, theft

I was recently crossing a lake that is commonly used for swimming and recreation. When I was swimming back to the shore, I was constantly nervous that my bag would be stolen, along with the keys in it. The lake spans several hundred metres, so there would have been opportunities for thieves taking our stuff. Luckily, everything was still in place.

I want to find a way to take the key to my flat and bike with me while swimming without any chance of losing them. I do not need more than the two keys and a towel (the mobile phone will stay at home).

**Edit:** Thank you all for the overwhelming amount of replies! I try also to follow all the comments and still don't know which of the replies I should pick for marking as the answer because so many of them are so great. :-)

Comment: Swimwear often come with small pouches for small objects. Have you not tried this? Is it impractical for you for some reason?

Comment: Too risky somehow. What if the seams loosen inside the pockets?
Then the key slips out of my pocket without even noticing it.

Comment: Note that many modern car keys, even without integrated remotes, have electronics in them and may not tolerate immersion.

Comment: Is the bike you're referring to a motorbike, or a bicycle? If it's a bicycle, this is a great example of why a combination lock is better than a lock with a key.

Comment: related question on Lifehacks.SE (https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/7035/how-to-protect-my-belongings-at-the-beach)

Comment: If you're swimming in a lake hopefully you have a tow float / buoy - you can always get a dry bag, fill it with bits (an extra air) and clip to that?

Comment: If your main concern is people stealing your bag, consider this out of the box solution: **Leave your keys outside your bag** (e.g. 1 cm underground below your bag). -- It is not foolproof, but it is now much less likely that a random passer by would take them away.

Comment: @Freiheit A solution to electronic keys is a ziplock bag.  Just make sure you try to get all the air out of it before sealing (so that it doesn't float awkwardly) and to seal it very well (so water doesn't get in).

Comment: Cork on a key chain is a simple solution.

Comment: @Roflo, as Bruder suggests, simply using a pocket can often lead to problems. I have known people to lose things out of their pockets this way. My father once swam in a lake, forgetting his wallet was in his pocket, and he lost the wallet in the lake - along with the money from his paycheck he had just cashed.

Answer (score 49):

Lots of swim/board shorts come with key keepers in the pockets. Chances are you may even have one in the swimwear you own. It's simply a length of elastic cord stitched into your pocket. If you don't have one, it can easily be added. You attach your keys to the loop using a girth hitch:

[image]

Comment: Is that the same as a larks-foot knot?

Comment: @TobySpeight Essentially, they are similar in appearance, but the difference is a girth hitch is tied with a closed loop, the Larks-foot (aka [Cow Hitch](http://www.animatedknots.com/cow/index.php)) is tied using the open end of a rope. When securing keys you want it to be to a closed loop so it can't slip off.

Comment: Lake swimming doesn't always mean this kind of clothing though - many lake swimmers I see are either in wetsuits or speedos... Though if you're wearing these then it's a good option :)

Comment: I can confirm that this solution is brilliant. I use this method when windsurfing.

Comment: @Aravona my winter wetsuit has a key keeper pounch on the lower the leg. For my summer suit I put the key on a thin rope around my neck and _inside the wetsuit_.

Comment: @Gusdor that's wetsuits though, not board shorts :) wetsuits often have these built in, especially semi and dry suits where it's often weird to not have a pocket.

Comment: @Aravona I get irrationally annoyed when my suit doesn't feature a pocket. Its a killer feature.

Comment: It's much, much harder to find this feature in women's swimwear.

Comment: @1006a Stitch a loop of elastic anywhere inside your suit. It's that easy to add the feature.

Comment: I already upvoted your answer anyway, because I think it's a great solution for some folks/suits; I just don't know that this answer is as practical for women's swimwear (I have definitely had swimsuits that would not have easily accommodated a key). Possibly men who prefer the itty-bitty Speedo over board shorts would have a similar issue.

Comment: @1006a A hair elastic would be the simple solution then: girth hitch the key to the hair elastic, then you can put it in your hair, wear it on your wrist or your ankle, or even girth hitch it again to one of the straps of your bathing suit.

Comment: @ShemSeger i have lost so many hair bands in swimming pools :') -- some also change tightness/friction when wet. The girth hitch sounds more likely, but i would not entrust it with my keys in case it opens while floating in water. A large keyring might work, though I wouldn't want to damage my suit

Comment: @Aravona My 4-3 wetsuit has a [special key pocket on my thigh with a key keeper inside it](https://mec.imgix.net/medias/sys_master/high-res/high-res/8806156206110/5021537-BK000-ALT-POCKET.jpg?w=900&h=900&auto=format&q=30&fit=fill&bg=FFF), so it depends on the wetsuit, and I know people who keep stuff in the legs of their speedos (the knee-length ones).

Comment: Can you explain how to do this a little more clearly?

Comment: @andy Push a bite in the elastic through the hole in the key and fold the loop over the top.

Answer (score 37):

There are a few ways to do this in addition to the previous answer.  If you have a car with a hitch:
[image]

This is what we use when we SCUBA dive.

Since you are only swimming and presumably not going to great depths, you can also use a waterproof wallet.  I have two varieties:

[image]

Or:

[image]

The wallets tend to run less than $10, the hitch lock is more like $30-$50.

Comment: In the UK, car insurers do not appreciate the keysafe solution and you may find your insurance invalid if your car is broken into because you stored the car key in a keysafe. It is best to get a spare cut, take it with you and lock the original inside and out of sight.

Comment: Wow!  Would this also apply to using the external combination lock?  You lock your keys in the car and use the number pad to lock and unlock the car.

Comment: I'd advise against the hitch lock; it's [opened pretty easily](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A9_UPkg9GZ4).

Comment: SQB, Master brand locks in general are pretty easily opened.  There might be some other brand of hitch lock which is more secure.  In any case, bikes generally don't have hitches, so it wouldn't solve the OP's problem.

Answer (score 27):

We've has a similar question on Travel.SE. The answer below is largely based on [this other answer of mine](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/49082/22140).

### Invest in a  Dry Egg/Box

My suggestion is to carry your keys in the water with you when you go for a dip. Keys can easily fit in what is called a **freediving dry egg/box** which, as the name suggests, is a gadget used by divers to keep their stuff dry whilst in the water. These gadgets come in various different sizes, cost under €20 and look something like this ([image courtesy of ScubaStore](http://www.scubastore.com/scuba-diving/mares-plastic-dry-egg/5499/p)):

[image: freediving dry egg]
<sub>(source: [watersportswarehouse.co.uk](https://www.watersportswarehouse.co.uk/images/product/full/mares-personal-dry-box_415727.jpg))</sub>

I have a dry egg I've been using for five years now. I've taken it with me countless times out in the sea and it has done its job.

#### Test for Waterproofness

First thing you should do after purchasing your egg is to test ride its watertightness. Put a piece of paper in it, lock it up and throw it in a sink/bucket full of water. Then wiggle it around for a few minutes. Take it out, open it and check the paper: if it's wet you either did not close the egg properly or it leaks.

#### Wearing Tips

One possible way of carrying the egg whilst swimming could be  replacing the lanyard with a longer one so that you can wear it diagonally across one shoulder like a shoulder bag. Other options include tying it to your swimming trunks, wearing it around your waist, your neck, or wearing a rubber weight belt of the type used by freedivers on which you can strap the box. The needed comfort also depends in how much swimming you are planning to do.

Comment: +1 for thinking about the risks of hooking up the cord while swimming.

Answer (score 27):

If it's just the keys that need securing, I love key wristbands. They are properly secure and you have the key in sight if you are a bit paranoid about it ;) I prefer it over any kinds of bags on strings, as it gives you less of a hassle and less of a feeling you might lose that stuff dangling from your wrist at any moment.

If you hit your favourite online shop with "key wristband swimming", you should get some. Example:

[image: key wristband]

As an alternative for more than just keys, I find running belts with pouches quite helpful. Note that they are typically not waterproof, so if you need to take your smartphone, you will need to protect it separately.
Example:

[image: belt pouch]

Answer (score 22):

I would be very leary about taking keys out into the water - most car modern car keys are not particular water proof and if you lose it in the water, it's pretty much gone for good.

I use a combination lock box that attaches to my car. Eg something similar to this

[image]

This allows you to leave bigger items in the car and rely on the car locks to keep every thing else safe.

Comment: Note: for obvious reasons don't use this if your car has a key fob/push to start/unlock. If you have such a car, AFAIK you can remove the actual key form it...take that and use it.

Comment: Why is everyone assuming car keys when the question says house/bike?

Comment: This is the perfect answer for a bike too.

Comment: It would be more correct to say that this allows you to rely on the combination lock box to keep your car *and* your possessions safe. At least unless you get a combination lock box to keep your car key in that is *at least* as safe as the car.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - that is true. But I suspect most cars are much quicker and easier for a thief to break into than small steel boxes locked under a car =)

Comment: @DaveSmylie pair of bolt cutters and it is open. Keysafes are really easy to open and your car insurer may not be impressed if your car key is in there.

Comment: Opened [very easily](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Pyn0PeHJFU). All [too easily](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fdeMaWkJF2k).

Comment: @Gusdor you'd also have to prove your keys were in there in the first place.

Comment: @gusdor - so you need a pair of bolt cutters and then need to break into the lock box - which can be done but takes time and assumes the oppurtunistic thief has bolt cutters with them. Alternatively, to break into a car all you need is a decent rock from the ground and a few seconds.

Comment: @DaveSmylie I don't know what to tell you. I spend _a lot_ of time in the water at beaches and have heard some horror-stories about people having their vehicles raided with specialist tools. There are legitimate reasons to have bolt cutters in your van. There are also illegitimate ones (people are bastards)

Comment: You can typically get a spare key cut at any hardware store. It won't start your car, but it will still open the doors, so you can leave your chipped keys locked in the car, and take your spare door key out with you.

Answer (score 16):

As a nudist/naturist, I've been to resorts where I've rented a cabin or trailer and needed to keep the key with me. As the resort(s) deal with people who aren't wearing trunks or have pockets, the key they provided was attached to a coil wristband, much like a telephone receiver cord. I was then able to keep it around my wrist the whole day while swimming, hiking, playing tennis, etc. without concern of losing the key(s).

I've attached a stock photo as not to advertise for anyone; however, these keyrings were under USD $1 or GBP £0.76.
[image: Spiral Wrist Coil Key Chain]

Comment: This combines well with the "dry egg" answer if you have an electronic car key, too.

Answer (score 15):

Very low budget solution: Safety pin your key to your swimsuit--inside a pocket if possible.

Comment: And exactly what you do at swimming pools with your locker key.

Answer (score 10):

You can get waterproof belt pouches. I used to use them when I wore a wetsuit for kayaking (a drysuit makes this simpler). They'll easily hold cash + phone +keys, and are nicer for swimming with than something that trails round your neck. As kayaking sometimes involves swimming in white water with trees and rocks around, the pouches with lanyards would be snag hazards, especially carried round your neck. For short swims with more stuff I've used a small dry bag (the roll top sort).

Answer (score 9):

There is a product that launched in 2015 called [PocketBands](http://www.Pocketbands.com). It is a low profile silicone band/bracelet that has a hidden pocket. You insert your key on the underside and it stays secure while swimming, running or other activities. It only holds one key, so you would need to buy two for both your keys. I bought these when PocketBands were a Kickstarter project, and the keys do stay put! They are less than $10.

[image: PocketBands]

You mentioned being nervous about your bag the keys were in, which reminded me of another successful Kickstarter project for a really nice looking, innovative, theft proof **lightweight** backpack by [Loctote](http://www.loctote.com) which is made of a slash proof fabric. This was also featured on Shark Tank (a TV show that pitches innovative products to a group of investors). I hope this is helpful! The bag is intended to be locked to a fixed object, so being slash proof is important, as long as the lock holds it's less likely a target.

Comment: How would a backpack being slash proof prevent it from being stolen off a beach while its owner is swimming?

Comment: @stannius Per their website, the bag is intended to be locked to a fixed object: https://loctote.com/ - so being slash proof is important, as long as the lock holds it's less likely a target.  Of course if you put your slash proof backpack on the ground without locking it securely to a fixed object, then nothing will prevent it from being stolen.

Comment: @AdamDavis I thought the same thing as stannius. You should edit your comment-response in your answer; that makes your answer more useful.

Comment: @Aaron I haven't answered this question (this isn't my answer).  You can suggest an edit to the answer by clicking the little edit link on the lower left of the answer.  Generally, though, comments are sufficient for this sort of information.

Comment: @AdamDavis It is common on Stack Exchange to consider comments as temporary, and we are technically supposed to treat them as such. I do not disagree that "comments are generally sufficient," but pertinent information like this should be added to the answer itself. I have seen some people mass-delete comments that have not been worked into the answer after some time; not on "Outdoors SE" but on others (this place seems more level-headed in general). Anyway, I will suggest an edit.

Comment: @Aaron while I don’t disagree with the principle, I’ve had many long discussions with others about this on meta.se since comments were introduced nearly a decade ago, and the reality is much more complex than could be discussed in a comment thread. I hope your edit goes through, but if it doesn’t I expect the comments are sufficient to provide the information to later viewers.

Comment: @AdamDavis Oh yes, what I put forth in my previous comment should in no way be taken as my feelings of how comments should be used. I just know how they get swept away often. I personally am of the mindset that comments should be much more laissez-faire. Anyway, glad things are closer to that here on Outdoors.SE.

Answer (score 8):

If your trunks don't have a designated key pouch or you're a female you can tie your keys to the draw string inside your trunks or bikini top. If you have a key fob on your keychain leave it in your car or at home. If your car has a combination lock you can leave your keys in the car.

Comment: What if your car keys have an integrated fob and key?

Comment: @MJeffryes related sister site questions [Can valet keys get wet?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/33026/can-valet-keys-get-wet)

Comment: My car doesn't have a valet key. And more and more cars have smart keys, which probably shouldn't be immersed.

Comment: @MJeffryes - If you're a Navy SEAL you would probably swim with the FOB part in your mouth like a badass, Beyond that IDK what to tell you.

Comment: Almost all keyfobs and electronic car keys are sealed to at least IP65, which allows shallow immersion.  I'd still suggest using a waterproof bag in addition to the built in protection (which may be damaged during battery change, over time, or could malfunction for other reasons). Further, you can generally have a non-electronic key made which will only unlock the doors, but won't start the vehicle or remotely unlock/lock the vehicle.  This type of key can be taken swimming without issue, and you can leave your keys secured inside the locked vehicle while swimming.

Comment: Very few electronic keys are IP65.  They can handle splashes but that's about it.

Comment: I googled and couldn't find any info from the horses mouth but all the info coming from consumers suggests that they are more than splash proof. People go swimming, put them thru the washer, etc and they still work, so while I can't find anything to support them being IP65 I found lots of data to prove they are much more than splash proof.

Comment: I have a key/fob combo and regularly get mine soaking wet in the rain without even thinking about it and I've never had a problem.

Comment: @MJeffryes I have a Nissan with integrated key and fob. I took it to the hardware store and had them cut me a key. It won't start the car, but it'll unlock the door, so I can leave by fob key in the car and carry the cut key.

Comment: @MatthewWhited Very few keys are marked or noted in the user's manual as IP65.  However the internal requirements manufacturers place on keyfob suppliers are essentially equivalent to IP65. Again, they are consumer devices, and they provide no guarantees for a variety of reasons, but you can verify IP65 design by simply taking yours apart if you like. The design of the button opening seals and the case gasket all meet the IP65 (better, actually) standard. If they aren't re-sealed correctly after a battery change, or if the seals are weak due to time and exposure this doesn't apply.

Comment: as someone who repairs electronics... there are no water tight seals on those keys.

Comment: @MatthewWhited even if you do repair electronics that's a pretty broad statement coming from someone with a pretty broad title.. not that I disagree..

Comment: Okay, I'm just saying the only rubber in the majority of these keys is the pay.  there is no seal around the seam. but whateves, if you want to risk starting your car and replacing a $150+ key over acting like they are waterproof more power to you.

Comment: @MatthewWhited Every keyfob I've dealt with has had a seal. I guess the best answer, then, is your mileage may vary.  I admit I'm more familiar with Ford and related brands than other vehicles, and when I worked on the electronics for a second tier supplier it was for Ford. Perhaps other manufacturers have lower standards. I'd be very interested in seeing images of the insides of the fobs you've experienced limited or no sealing on.

Answer (score 8):

I use 3mm utility cord around my neck.  I tie in key with a [Girth Hitch](https://www.netknots.com/rope_knots/girth-hitch).  Or tie the key into the necklace.  I use a [double fisherman](https://www.netknots.com/rope_knots/double-fishermans) on the cord.

Comment: Keep in mind that 3mm cord is enough to hang/catch/choke you...

Answer (score 6):

It frustrates me that most of the answers are unfortunate variations of "just put the keys into your pocket"

The problem with that suggestion is that most sets of car keys include an electronic component with buttons for remotely interacting with the car.

The only other really viable answer I've seen is the Dry Egg thing, but that isn't entirely convenient.

On short notice what I would suggest is one of two things:

1) put the keys in a condom (and if you're worried about the key bursting the condom, but the keys in a plastic bag first), and then tie the condom.

2) buy a cheap jar of jam (or pasta sauce or something), empty it, wash it in the lake, put the keys in it, and put the lid back on. Now you have a dry key store.

Answer (score 5):

My swim trunks generally came with a tie string in the front to permit them to be securely fastened to my waist. So when I was a kid, my house key was merely tied into the string with the standard knot. I always used the same knot as I did for a shoelace, which is called a "Double Slip Knot." http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Double+Slip+Knot

The key would be tucked into my trunks along with the knot. This location may be a bit uncomfortable due to the convergence of dangling brass with other dangling parts, but it has the distinct advantage of simplicity.

The same thing worked for locker keys. Many swimming pools have lockers for your personal items, and this was one method used to keep the key attached.

Answer (score 4):

Most here have focused on taking the key with you to the lake, with the assumption that you have taken your car. Here is slightly different solution:

My house has an electronic lock with [keycode](https://www.safe.co.uk/products/yale-keyfree-with-remote-module-chrome.html?ACODE=googlebase&gclid=CjwKCAjwk4vMBRAgEiwA4ftLs7FlT_JudOaoyBQkpmDSN8Mq4iNd5zPfPyM0jIYdua4SMDzpxv2e0xoCYO0QAvD_BwE). This might seem extreme/expensive but it is useful for more than just going swimming. If you are not taking your car to the beach/lake then this better than the car key safe option. Going for runs/cycles in clothing without pockets is a great help. You don't have to worry about loosing the key of heavy night at the pub and long trips away. Letting trusted guests in without a key is also very helpful. It has temporary codes so you can set/delete/change this after.

Another similar and less costly solution is to have a [combination key safe](http://www.screwfix.com/p/master-lock-5-key-combination-key-safe/77908?kpid=77908&gclid=CjwKCAjwk4vMBRAgEiwA4ftLs53cCgD6t4VZO73YzOUOyCuKSKTIDEqWk89pMrpgLIAOceNwsCrsjBoCtv0QAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds&dclid=CLfux6TnutUCFTgx0wod8rMBZQ). This has most of the same advantages but for a slight lack in convenience.

Comment: The combination key safes are very common, and not inconvenient at all :) some holiday home companies use them

Comment: Yes, The key safes are not uncommon. The electronic locks are less common. The main reason I have one on my front door is that my family run a B&B. We also have a key safe for a barn we rent out. Now that I have used the electronic lock I don't think I will ever go back. It is so very handy!

Answer (score 2):

Kind of like the key keeper on the swim trunks. Some young girls make a cord like that that goes around your ankle to sell at S. Pacific beach's. They seem to work. Elastic cord.